# Is it normal surface of general type to have infinitely many positive rank elliptic curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

> [Answered at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/214870/15503).

I am not good at algebraic geometry and almost surely am
misunderstanding something.

Got an alleged argument against Bombieri-Lang conjecture and
would like to know what the mistake is.

One of the most simplest formulations of Bombieri-Lang conjecture
is in [Joe Silverman's answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214422/fermats-last-theorem-pm-k/214452#comment529948_214452), paraphrasing

> ...For a surface of general type ... the Bombieri-Lang conjecture says that the solutions in rational numbers ...are.. not Zariski dense (**lie on a finite set of curves**).

Take the affine surface over the rationals:

$$ z^6 + x^4 - y^2=0$$

According to Magma it is of general type.

Fix $z$ squarefree integer $k$. This gives quartic model
of elliptic curve $k^6+x^4-y^2=0$.

This is birationally equivalent to Weierstrass $$v^2=-4k^6u+u^3 $$

As $k$ varies, this gives infinitely many positive rank elliptic curves.

> What is wrong with this alleged contradiction?

---

Comment suggests it might be not of general type.

In Magma online:  http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

```
 K<x,y,z,t>:=ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(),3);
 p:=z^6 + x^4*t^2 - y^2*t^4;
 S:=Surface(K,p);
 KodairaEnriquesType(S);
 KodairaDimension(S);
 //returns:
 // 2 0 General type
 // 2
```

---

**Added** The main misunderstanding was caused by incorrect usage of
Magma function. The correct way to check is `KodairaEnriquesType(S : CheckADE := true);` because of certain assumptions, but this might take much longer.

With this change I get error and no result.

Comment: I am not an expert on surfaces, but my intuition tells me that your surface is not of general type, but rather an elliptic surface.

Comment: @JesperPetersen You well might be right. Edited with Magma online code, error in it (or in Magma) might answer the question.

Comment: @JesperPetersen There was typo in the code, but the result is the same. Just edited.

Comment: Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214870/is-it-normal-surface-of-general-type-to-have-infinitely-many-positive-rank-ellip

Comment: I am not knowledgeable about how to compute Kodaira dimensions, but my intution works this way. An elliptic surface is a surface that has a lot of elliptic curves on it. You have from your surface a morphism to the projective line, such that the fibers, or preimages, are elliptic curves. Or rephrased, your surface is just a $1$-parameter family of elliptic curves.

Comment: @JesperPetersen Thank you. This appears to contradict the Magma output, unless there is error in my short code.

Comment: @JesperPetersen Likely you are right. This appears to be "feature" (not a bug) in Magma. Check the MO comments.

Comment: Jesper Petersen is right; this is a singular model of an elliptic surface.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered at MO.